# Repeating mysql error in OSX console

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, console, battery-life

I'm getting an endlessly repeating set of errors in my mac's console that go as follows:

```
Jan  6 00:21:37 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mysql.mysqld): Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.mysql.mysqld[84683]: 130106 00:21:46 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Air.local.err'.
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84731]): Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:9386 (26200):0
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84731]): Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap.
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84731]): _vprocmgr_switch_to_session(): kr = 0x44c
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84732]): Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:9386 (26200):0
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84732]): Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap.
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.apple.launchd[1] (0x7ffbca610db0.anonymous.nohup[84732]): _vprocmgr_switch_to_session(): kr = 0x44c
Jan  6 00:21:46 Air com.mysql.mysqld[84683]: 130106 00:21:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
Jan  6 00:21:47 Air com.mysql.mysqld[84683]: 130106 00:21:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Air.local.pid ended
```

I'm concerned that these repeating errors may be ruining my battery life. How can these be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: It is in a re-launch loop. Basically you have mysqld on auto start but mysqld fail to start correctly and die and OS is trying to restart it again. How did you install mysqld? Which verison of OS X you running?

Comment: I'm running OS X Lion 10.7.5 and I installed the MySQL package from the MySQL site.